# Angular limit to first ng-if TRUE item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hej, how do I show only the first number that evaluates to true inside ng-repeat?

In my directive (or controller) I have:

```
ctrl.things = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

and in my html:

```
<div ng-repeat='thing in ctrl.things' >
    <span ng-if="thing>3" ng-show="$first">{{thing}}</span>
</div>
```

How do I display only 4 as a result?

Please bear in mind that this example is simplified. There is actually an ng-repeat inside ng-repeat and because of that (and other things) there are not many things I co do inside the directive (controller). Many thanks for any solution.

Comment: code is not correctly formatted it seems

Comment: It's because of the `>` operator used in the HTML which is being treated as a end tag HTML.

Comment: Code works fine. It my display strangely in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a method in the scope

```
$scope.getData=function(obj){
      return obj > 3;
    }
```

Then add this as filter in div

```
<div ng-repeat='thing in things | filter : getData'  ng-if="$first"> 
    <span >{{thing}}</span>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnfycp8a/)**</kbd>

If wanna to use `this`

Try like this

Declare a method in the scope

```
vm.getData=function(obj){
  return obj > 3;
}
```

Then add this as filter in div

```
 <div ng-repeat='thing in vm.things | filter : vm.getData'  ng-if="$first"> 
    <span >{{thing}}</span>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnfycp8a/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
//controller
$scope.ctrl={};
$scope.ctrl.things=[{1:false},{2:false},{3:false},{4:true},{5:true}];
$scope.check=function(value){
 $scope.count = value === true?($scope.count+1):$scope.count;
 return $scope.count ===1 ;
}
//end of controller
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat='(key,value) in ctrl.things' >
    <span ng-if="check(value)">{{key}}</span>
</div>
```

To show first element if you want to show last item you can put `ng-if="$last"`

Comment: You've missed the ng-if statement that is crucial here.

Comment: Are you asking for nested ng-repeat and want to show first element of every first element of second ng-repeat???

Comment: Disregard the second ng-repeat, it's not that relevant here. I want to show the first result that is true inside ng-repeat. I want to display "4" in my example.

Comment: @Baki check my answer

Comment: I guess you want something like this.. please hav a look on edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You should have to create a filter or inline it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='thing in ctrl.things' ng-if="thing > 3">
    <span ng-if="$first">{{thing}}</span>
</div>
```

That should work